# Is there a camera app which would let you access the gallery?

Tags: applications, camera, gallery

In [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12483868/903186) user [@Parth Mehrotra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1060955/parth-mehrotra) writes:

> You can't really change the things camera intent has to offer, and if
>   you do find a device where the **camera app would let you access the
>   gallery** I wouldn't depend on it.

I am a user of the [BuitenBeter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yucat.buitenbeter) app. With this app Dutch civilians can easily report issues to their municipality by taking pictures. **The app offers me only the possibility to upload pictures from the camera and not from the gallery.** I spend several hours looking for an app which I would name `Camera2Gallery`, which would appear as a extra option in the screenshot below.

[image]

Does it exist? Can it be easily made? I think there is a real big need.

Comment: Maybe just mail them, there's contact info below the play store description. I'd say the app has to support it properly, don't try ugly workarounds?

Comment: I think it would be very easy to write an app that does exactly this, since it would basically be registering an Intent Filter that would simply start an intent to pick a photo from whichever gallery application that user has. I'd be surprised if no one has written this.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no app like this that I am aware of.

However, you could ask the app developer of the app you are using to allow pictures to be taken from the gallery, and not only a new picture - this is very possible.